# Mi JTabbedPane Se duplica

Tags: java, java-swing

Saludos.
Tengo un problema con un JTabbedPane dentro de un JDialog. Lo que me sucede es que cargo la ventana con datos que se muestran en 3 diferentes paneles de un JTabbedPane. La primera vez que llamo al JFrame principal no hay problema. Pero la segunda vez que la llamo, al abrir el JDialog este aparece desconfigurado y en lugar de aparecer mis 3 paneles, aparecen 6 y asi se siguen agregando de 3 en 3 cada vez que llamo la ventana sin haber cerrado la aplicación.
He buscado en muchas páginas y no encuentro una solución. Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan prestarme.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu codigo actual, asi recibiras mejores respuestas

Comment: El asunto es que por la premura de la entrega del sistema, utilicé netbeans para la creación de las ventanas y me confié de las herramientas gráficas que esta IDE ofrece. Es por eso que no doy con el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has probado a borrar los paneles anteriormente creados? Si no los has borrado, asegúrate de ello, si no quieres borrarlos ten cuidado con no crearlos de nuevo, simplemente vuelve ha hacerlos visibles. Este tipo de objetos no los recoge el recolector de basura a menos que los borres.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Era exactamente eso lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @JackReacher Si esta respuesta te ayudo, marcala como **respuesta aceptada** con el boton en forma de V, asi ayudaras a otros usuarios a encontrar mejores respuestas mas rapido y tu ganaras reputación por ayudar a la comunidad